# Pygame showing only a black screen

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.8

I am new to Pygame, so I was doing some testing before starting an actual game but when I executed the code, all I am getting is a black screen even though I have specified a color and I also tried using the `blit` method but is still showing only a black screen. Here is my code and the output on Ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.8:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

s = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,500))

testImg = pygame.image.load('player.png')
testX = 500
testY = 250

def test(x, y):
    s.blit(testImg, (x,y))

# Game Loop:
running = True
while running:
    s.fill((113,113,113))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    test(testX, testY)
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to update the display by [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) at the end of the application loop:

```py
running = True
while running:
    s.fill((113,113,113))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    test(testX, testY)

    pygame.display.flip() # <---
```

A minimal [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Comment: Thanks... Did not know that

Comment: @Shreeniket987 Thank you. You're welcome.